# TensorFlow check which protobuf implementation is being used

Tags: installation, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to check which protobuf implementation is used by TensorFlow (i.e. if it is using the C++ version or the Python one)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@keveman's answer tells us the *default* implementation but not the *active* implementation.

Importantly, the `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable affects which implementation is active so

```
PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation._default_implementation_type)"
```

and

```
PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation._default_implementation_type)"
```

will always show the same result.

To see which implementation is active, use this instead:

```
python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation.Type())"
```

Changing the `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable will cause the result of `Type()` to change where it didn't for `_default_implementation_type`.

Comment: It seems that Tensorflow always call the cpp  protobuf if installed from source. Since after I set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION to python, I still get "large protocol message ...  larger than 67108864 bytes".  While protobuf 3.3.0 should use the BytesLimit = 2G.

Comment: 'upb' is https://github.com/protocolbuffers/upb

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
$ python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation._default_implementation_type)"
```

It should print either `python` or `cpp`.

Comment: Thank you! It said `python`. I'm assuming I won't get the best performance with that setting?

Comment: I was able to install the pip package by simply renaming the package.

wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl
mv protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp34-none-linux_x86_64.whl protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install x86_64.whl protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl

It still says I am using 'python'. Whats going on here?